# What is wrong with my code? Usaco: Friday the Thirteenth

Tags: c++

I am screwed with my own code. This problem is from train.usaco.org: Friday The Thirteen.

Here is the objective:  That is, does the 13th of the month land on a Friday less often than on any other day of the week? To answer this question, write a program that will compute the frequency that the 13th of each month lands on Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, and Saturday over a given period of N years.

And here is my code:

```
/*
ID: erdemtu2
PROG: friday
LANG: C++
*/
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int horwuul(int month, int year){
    if(month == 2)
        return ((year % 4) || (!(year % 100) && ((year+300) % 400))) ? 28 : 29;
    switch(month){
        case 3:
        case 5:
        case 9:
        case 11:
            return 30;
            break;
        default:
            return 31;
            break;
    }
}

int main() {
    //freopen("friday.in", "r", stdin);
    //freopen("friday.out", "w", stdout);

    int a, i, j;
    cin >> a;
    if(a < 0) a = 0;
    if(a > 400) a = 400;

    int ans[7]={0};
    //was int ans[7];

    int q=0, month=0;
    for(i = 0; i < a; i++)
        for(j = 0; j < 12; j++){
            ans[((q + 6) % 7)]++;
            q = (q + horwuul(j, i)) % 7;
        }

    for(i = 0; i < 7; i++){
        cout << ans[(i + 6) % 7];
        cout << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Expected

- Input: 20
- Output: 36 33 34 33 35 35 34

Mine
  was:
 - Output: 36 4233426 2293443 2293497 2293733 1996393719 -52161590
  now:
-Output: 38 34 35 33 33 34 33

And what am i mistaking on? Any help would be great, and thanks for response.

Comment: The question seems to assume that all periods of N years have the same "13th" distribution.

Comment: anyhoops, initialize your `ans` array (e.g. `int ans[7] = {0}`).

Comment: Thanks for response. And thanks for letting me know how to use loops with arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each year starts with January. You can decide whether January is 0 or 1, but you should be consistent.